# Rails .blank? returns true when it shouldnt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In the next action below @city.id.blank? doesnt return nil,when i dont choose any city.And even in the log it shows blank but in the controller next action  `unless @city.id.blank?`  still returns true. what is going on here?Thank you in advance

form

```
<%= form_for :city,:size=>"40", :url=>{:action =>"next"} do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name ,:prompt=>"Select your city")  %>
```

controller

```
  def next
    @city=City.find(params[:city][:city_id]) 
    unless @city.id.blank? 
      session[:city_id] = @city.id
      redirect_to show_home_path
    else
      redirect_to :controller=>"home" ,:action=>"index" 
    end
  end
```

log

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"7N5sQqKGKlK5IdXnj81629p1R0p+OpkhhvZDC1PjtHQ=", "city"=> {"city_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"continue"}
City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" = ?  LIMIT 1  [["id", ""]]
```

Comment: For `City.find`, if there are no object found, an error will be raised...

Comment: @PeterWong: That depends on what's behind the models. MongoMapper's `find` returns `nil` for example.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using and what are your models based on (ActiveRecord, MongoMapper, ...)?

Comment: What happens if you say `City.find('')` in the Rails console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked the solution was to use `find_by_id` instead of find because `find` raises an exception when it can't find the object, which is not `nil`. `find_by_id` only returns `nil` when it can't find the object.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, seems better than mine at least :)

Comment: So in short: `.blank?` was never the problem at all.

Answer (score 5):

Your `params[:city][:city_id]` is an empty string so `@city` will be `nil` (or you'll get an exception depending on what's behind your models):

```
@city = City.find(params[:city][:city_id])
```

But `nil` responds to the `id` method with a non-blank value (or an exception depending on which version of Ruby you're using). You should be looking at `@city.blank?`, `@city.nil?`, or just `@city` rather than looking at `@city.id`:

```
if @city
  session[:city_id] = @city.id
  redirect_to show_home_path
else
  ...
```

Comment: `unless @city.blank?` returned true too though

Comment: @mu is too short I am using ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @katie: Interesting. What is in `@city` and `@city.id`? And where does your `find` method come from?

Comment: `@city and @city.id `they are both blank

Comment: you can look at the log is just blank city_id

Answer (score 0):

You code is not working because when your @city is blank 
and you do

@city.id.blank?

nil.id = 4 
its actually doing 4.blank? 
which is false